# Django Models internal methods

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django so I just made up an project to get to know it but I'm having a little problem with this code, I want to be able to as the car obj if it is available so I do a:

```
>>>cars = Car.objects.all()
>>>print cars[0].category
>>>'A'
>>>cars[0].available(fr, to)
```

that results in a:

```
>>>global name 'category' is not defined
```

So it seems that I don't have access to the self.category within the class, any ideas?

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):

    TRANSMISSION_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Manual'),
        ('A', 'Automatic'),
    )

    category = models.CharField("Category",max_length=1,primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField("Description",max_length=200)
    numberOfCars = models.IntegerField("Number of cars")
    numberOfDoors = models.IntegerField("Number of doors")
    transmission = models.CharField("Transmission", max_length=1, choices=TRANSMISSION_CHOICES)
    passengers = models.IntegerField("Number of passengers")
    image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d")

    def available(self, fr, to):
        rents = Rent.objects.filter(car=self.category)
        rents = rents.excludes(start < fr)
        rents = rents.exclude(end > to)

        return cont(rents)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Class " + self.category

class Rent(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    childrenSeat = models.BooleanField()
    extraDriver = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.car) + " From: " + str(self.start) + " To: " + str(self.end)
```

Comment: Your sample sessions isn't formatted properly, so it's hard to see what is going on.  I don't see any reason in the code why you'd get a complaint about "category".  Are you sure this code really produces that error?

Comment: I've formatted the code by taking a look at the raw text, and I really don't see how you could get that error.

Comment: Yes it produces that error. What is wrong with the formatting?

Comment: Please give the full traceback.

Comment: File "/mysite/bookings/models.py", line 19, in available
    rents = Rent.objects.filter(car=self.category)
NameError: global name 'category' is not defined

is the exact error I get when i do:

>>> from mysite.bookings.models import Car, Rent
>>> cars = Car.objects.all()
>>> cars[0].available(start, end)

Comment: >>> from mysite.bookings.models import Car, Rent
>>> cars = Car.objects.all()
>>> cars[0].available(start, end)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/david/Documents/workspace/djangoTest/src/mysite/../mysite/bookings/models.py", line 19, in available
    rents = Rent.objects.filter(car=self.category)
NameError: global name 'category' is not defined


is the full traceback

Comment: @davideagle: Do not comment on your own question.  Please update your question with new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't see how the error you are getting relates to it, the filter you are using doesn't look correct.

You define category as a string in the Car model:

```
category = models.CharField("Category",max_length=1,primary_key=True)
```

And define car as a foreignkey in the Rent model:

```
car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

And then you try and filter Rents:

```
rents = Rent.objects.filter(car=self.category)
```

But car should be a model here, not a charfield. Perhaps you meant to say car=self?

Comment: Thanks. I realized what my issue was, i was running "python manage.py shell" and I thought it was enough to re-import my package after I made a change to it. I was dead wrong. As soon as I quit the shell and did this allover again my code got updated and the error went away. Thanks for the tip on car=self, car=self.category was my db oriented thinking :)

Comment: Using QuerySets there are also other ways of getting the data you want. For example, since there is a foreignkey, you can use rents = self.rent_set